# Google Analytics Content Group, do I use gtag set or gtag config?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I am trying to separate my site pages using "content group" in google analytics.
So that I track how different page titles perform. 
I don't know which of these two is the right way to modify html code to track each group.

Do I use what I see under `admin > property > view > content grouping` ?

```
gtag('set', {'content_group1': 'My Group Name'});
```

**OR**
what I see at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&utm_id=adcode

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'content_group1': 'My Group Name'});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content group passed with `set` command will be added to the next hit, like:

```
gtag('set', {'content_group1': 'My Group Name'}); \\ No data sent

gtag('event', <action>, {                 \\ Now data will  include content group
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

Usually you'd want to have it sent with the first page view hit so `gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'content_group1': 'My Group Name'});` would work fine for you.

Comment: Thanks, so if I use it like this, then I don't need the `set` and `event` ? `gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'content_group1': 'My Group Name'});`

Comment: No you don't need it when you pass `content_group1` with `config`

Comment: If I want to send information for more than 1 content group (content_group1, content_group2...) , It is ok to do more than one call to gtag('config'?

Comment: @JorgeRamírez yes, it's fine